# Se presenta un inconveniente al grabar varias filas de un jtable

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo un Jtable que contiene filas insertadas desde una base de datos, la ultima columna es un checkbox. Este el codigo para grabar la fila cada vez que hago click en el checkbox:

```
protected void btnEnviarActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tbDocSolicitud.getModel();
        int[] selectedRow = tbDocSolicitud.getSelectedRows();


        for(int t : selectedRow){
            if((Boolean)model.getValueAt(t, 14) == true){
                String codArchivo = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 0);
                String codCentroCosto = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 1);
                String tipoArchivo = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 4);
                String doc = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 6);
                String nivelArchivo = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 7);
                String lote = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 9);
                String fila = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 10);
                String usuarioSolicita = Constante.idUsuario;
                String fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
                String fechaSolicita = fecha;
                Objeto object = (Objeto) cboCentroCostoDestino.getSelectedItem();
                String centroCostoDestino = ((Objeto)object).getCodigo();
                String centroCostoOrigen = Constante.c_ccosto;
                if (centroCostoDestino.equals("0")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seleccione el Destino del Documento","Alerta",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    cboCentroCostoDestino.requestFocus();
                }
                else{
                    MovimientoArchivoDTO m = new MovimientoArchivoDTO();
                    m.setC_c_archivo(codArchivo);
                    CentroCostoDTO c = new CentroCostoDTO();
                    c.setC_ccosto(codCentroCosto);
                    m.setC_ccosto(c);
                    m.setC_ccosto_origen(centroCostoOrigen);
                    m.setC_ccosto_destino(centroCostoDestino);
                    m.setC_tipo_doc(tipoArchivo);
                    m.setC_t_doc(doc);
                    m.setC_c_nivel_archivo(nivelArchivo);
                    m.setLote(lote);
                    m.setFila(fila);
                    m.setC_c_usuario_solicita(usuarioSolicita);
                    m.setD_dt_solicita(fechaSolicita);
                    int estado = x.RegistrarSolicitud_SA(m);
                    if (estado == 1){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,doc);            
                    }
                    else
                        mensaje("Error en enviar");
                }
            }
        }
        ListarDocumentoSA(Constante.c_ccosto, estado_flg);
    }
```

Cuando hago click a la casilla del checkbox de UNA fila y le hago click al boton grabar si se graba, pero el problema es que cuando hago click a la casilla del checkbox de TRES o MAS filas solo se guarda una y no se guardan las que tienen el check en la casilla.

Comment: Ya verificaste si tu tbDocSolicitud.getSelectedRows() te recupera las tres casillas o n.. cantidad de filas seleccionadas System.out.println("Seleccionadas: " + tbDocSolicitud.getSelectedRows().size), ¿guarda el primero o el ultimo de la lista?

Comment: Selecciono la casilla de la primer fila luego la casilla de la segunda fila y cuando le doy grabar solo se graba la segunda fila

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JTable** obtener el valor **checkbox** cuando casilla de verificación está marcada

```
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
              @Override
              public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                   for(int i=0;i<table.getModel().getRowCount();i++)
                      {
                        if ((Boolean) table.getModel().getValueAt(i,0))
                        {  
                          System.out.println(">\t"+table.getSelectedRow());
                          break;
                        }
                     }     
                  }
        });
```

Tambien encontre un ejemplo muy bien explicado [Aqui](http://www.jc-mouse.net/java/jcheckbox-dentro-jtable-con-netbeans)